# React Troubles when trying to update states from props

Tags: reactjs, state, react-props

today i come to you because i have some issues with the app im building,
what i'm trying to do is update my component's state when the parent's state is updating, i've aleady tried to pick solutions from there but none of them is working

here is what my child component looks like:

```
class SideBarSimu extends component{
  constructor(props){
    this.state = {
      addedConfigs: { },
      // should looks like { key1: { property1: {} , property2: {}}, ... }
      cached: {  },
      // used to compare the addedConfig[key] im editing with the new prop
      editing: null, // the addedConfig key im currently edting
      ...
    }
  }
  // here i put the methods im trying
  ...
  render(){
    ...
  }
}
```

And here are the things i've tried so far:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    console.log(this.state.cached)
    console.log(nextProps.moduleDetails)
    if(nextProps.moduleDetails !== this.props.moduleDetails && this.state.editing !== null){
      let temp = this.props.getModules() // returns the parent's state i need to store into this.state.addedConfigs[key], can't use this.props because i need to add extra keys
      let configs = {...this.state.addedConfigs}
      configs[this.state.editing] = temp
      this.setState({ addedConfigs: configs })
    }
  }
```

that did not worked at all so i tried that:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps (nextProps, prevState) {
    if(nextProps.moduleDetails !== prevState.cached && prevState.editing !== null) {
      let temp = nextProps.getModules()
      let config = {...prevState.addedConfigs}
      config[prevState.editing] = temp
      return {
        addedConfigs: config, 
        cached: nextProps.moduleDetails
      };
    } else {
      return null
    }
  }
```

And here is the last thing i've tried:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
    if(nextProps.moduleDetails !== nextState.cached && nextState.editing !== null){
      let temp = this.props.getModules()
      let config = {...nextState.addedConfigs}
      config[nextState.editing] = temp
      this.setState({ addedConfigs: config, cached: nextProps.moduleDetails })
    }
    return true
  }
```

on the first time i assign this.state.editing it actually works but when i make changes to the parents state it does not validate the if statement, so i think i might missunderstand something right there

any help would be appreciated

Comment: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html

Comment: `componentWill...` methods are deprecated in favor of `componentDid...` methods now

Comment: I don't understand `addedConfigs = { },` Why not `addedConfigs: { },` ?

Comment: if you sould force update?? with `this.forceUpdate()` here docs https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html or try callback from setState, something like that  `this.setState({ key: value }, function() {
  // callbak -> this.state is updated
});`

Comment: Sterling Archer: i'll try that, did not know
Stever: my bad i've update, i should have copy/paste but there to much unrelated things in my component
Jorge Felix Cazarez: i've never heard of this.forceUpdate, i'll look into that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i've fixed it, i just changed the condition and now it's working as i expect it. I also removed my cached state as i dont need it anymore.

My code:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps (nextProps, prevState) {
    if(prevState.editing !== null) {
      let temp = nextProps.getModules()
      let config = {...prevState.addedConfigs}
      config[prevState.editing] = temp
      return {
        addedConfigs: config, 
      };
    } else {
      return null
    }
  }
```